# Create relationship between nodes created from UNWIND list

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, unwind

I am passing into a Cypher query a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, which I am using to create a series of nodes based on the key-value pairs contained in the `Map<String, Object>`.

I now want to be able to link those nodes together, in the order they were unwound.

Current cypher/java code:

```java
public static void doMergeAndLink(List<Map<String, Object>> nodeProperties)
{
    try (Session session = driver.session())    
    {
        session.run("UNWIND $nodeProperties AS np " +
            "MERGE (n:Event {name:np.name, location: np.location, eventDate:np.eventDate}) "
        , parameters("nodeProperties",nodeProperties));
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

What I want now is to be able to add `MERGE (n)-[:NEXT_EVENT]->(n+1)` but I don't know the Cypher to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apoc.coll.pairsMin` you can extract pairs of adjacent node properties: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/data-structures/collection-list-functions/

So in their example,

```
apoc.coll.pairsMin([1,2,3]) YIELD value
```

returns:

```
[[1,2],[2,3]]
```

So to put it into practice and link adjacent pairs of nodes created from a list of maps, I created a list similar to your $nodeProperties, and linked them:

```
WITH [{a: "foo0", b: "bar0"}, {a: "foo1", b: "bar1"}, {a: "foo2", b: "bar2"}] as allNodes
WITH apoc.coll.pairsMin(allNodes) as nodePairs
UNWIND nodePairs as pair
MERGE (n0:Foo {name: pair[0].a, prop: pair[0].b})
MERGE (n1:Foo {name: pair[1].a, prop: pair[1].b})
MERGE (n0)-[:RELATION]-(n1)
RETURN *
```

[image: Nodes linked together]

Comment: Thanks, this does answer the question - I'll hold out for a bit in case anyone comes up with an non-apoc answer though.

Comment: Hmm - if you're keen to avoid apoc, you could perhaps do something like `UNWIND range(0, length(list)-1) as i` to give you a list of indexes, and then create nodes by indexing into the list: `MERGE (e1:Event {name: list[i].name}), MERGE (e2:Event {name: list[i+1].name}), CREATE (e1)-[:REL]-(e2)`?

There might be some messing about with array indexes to make sure i+1 doesn't go off the end etc - I've not tried it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNWIND to create a linked nodes. First create the nodes for your nodeProperties list then create the NEXT_EVENT relationship.

Below query will create a node1 linked to node2 in your list $nodeProperties.  UNWIND will create another list of index numbers from 0 to end (except the last item). Then merge (or match if it exists) the node based on the name (assuming your node primary key is name). Then create the needed relationship :NEXT_EVENT. Unwind is like a FOR LOOP so it will link item1 to item2 then item2 to item3 ... until item99 to item100.

```
 WITH $nodeProperties AS np 
 UNWIND range(0, size(np) - 2) as idx
 MERGE (node1:Event {name:np[idx].name, location: np[idx].location, eventDate:np[idx].eventDate})
 MERGE (node2:Event {name:np[idx+1].name, location: np[idx+1].location, eventDate:np[idx+1].eventDate})
 CREATE (node1)-[:NEXT_EVENT]->(node2)
```

Comment: Are there any efficiency issues with effectively merging each of the nodes (except the first and last) twice?

Comment: I have no issues on it.